# is that possible to add more "https endpoints" for the workers kubeconfig?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, ovh, azure-aks

I am trying to add at this **--server** argument three https endpoint to make it HA. Is that possible?

```sh
kubectl config set-cluster Zarsk \
    --certificate-authority=ca.pem \
    --embed-certs=true \
    --server=https://${k8s_PUBLIC_ADDRESS}:6443 \
    --kubeconfig=${instance}.kubeconfig
```

Answer (score 2):

No, only a single connection URL is supported